# Как правильно передать индекс tabitem через кнопку в tabItem.header

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

Есть форма с tabControl:

```
<TabControl  x:Name="tabs">
```

tabItem следующего вида:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Margin="3">Tab 1</TextBlock>
            <Button/>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
</TabItem>
```

Для кнопки в стилях указано следующее:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Content" Value ="x"/>
      <Setter Property="IsCancel" Value ="True"/>
      <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Button_Click"/>
  </Style>
```

Как при нажатии на кнопку вызвать закрытие вкладки, на которой расположена кнопка?

Я пробовал делать так:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabItem = e.Source as TabItem;

        tabs.Items.Remove(tabItem);            
    }
```

Однако Удаления таба не происходит.
Инструкцию эту нашёл на просторах интернета, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно передавал данные:

```
private TabItem GetTargetTabItem(object originalSource)
    {
        var current = originalSource as DependencyObject;

        while (current != null)
        {
            var tabItem = current as TabItem;
            if (tabItem != null)
            {
                return tabItem;
            }

            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        }

        return null;
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabItem = GetTargetTabItem(e.OriginalSource);
        tabs.Items.Remove(tabItem);            
    }
```